# Android Dialog OnClick methods not working?

Tags: java, android

I built an AlertDialog in this class file, and the dialog box is coming up fine, however the methods dont seem to be calling when a click is performed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

```
//AlertView Builder
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(" ");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.banner);
    builder.setMessage("Share this picture using any of the below!");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Email",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  System.out.print("Emailing...");
                }
            });

    builder.setNeutralButton("Facebook",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    System.out.print("Facebooking...");
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Twitter",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    System.out.print("Tweeting...");
                }
            });
```

Comment: show me the code from where are you calling the method? And where the method is declared??

Comment: for now the methods are just the system.out.println statements, but they are never getting executed

Comment: yeah. try to use the statement given below by JRaymond.

Comment: Deckare either neutral button only, or positive and negative button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you expecting it to do? do you have any code in those blocks that you don't have up there right now?

Android doesn't by default use `System.out.print();` for anything - use Log:

```
Log.d(getClass().getName(),"Facebooking...");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been using System.out.println and it has been showing up in logcat, but not here. Your change worked though. I wonder why it wouldnt work in this context here...

Comment: @russ216 I think that there are certain contexts for which it will work, where the android team has piped system.out to logcat - but a dialog is actually a separate activity with a separate window, so it might not have the same kinds of access, so better to get in the habit of using their logging system - the control is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code as `setNeutralButton`,`setPositiveButton`,`setNegativeButton` doesn't work specific to particular API's.

```
//AlertView Builder
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(" ");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.banner);
    builder.setMessage("Share this picture using any of the below!");

    builder.setButton1("Email",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  System.out.print("Emailing...");
                }
            });

    builder.setButton2("Facebook",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    System.out.print("Facebooking...");
                }
            });

    builder.setButton3("Twitter",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    System.out.print("Tweeting...");
                }
            });
```

Hope it helps...